# C++ Make program to accept plugins

Tags: c++, windows, plugins

Before all, I want to say that I found other questions here about this matter but this one is a bit different

The only thing that I want from plugin system is that plugins can hook my functions
Think that I have this function :

```
DWORD TestFunc(int Number)
{
   printf("The number is %i", Number);

   // Plugin codes here

   return 0; // Return when we have done our job
}
```

Where I placed `// Plugin codes here` I want my plugin codes goes here so it's able to use function stack and add code to function every time function calls

So plugin code should have something like this

```
Hook(char* FuncName, LPVOID /* or DWORD */ PluginFunc);
```

Which in the samle above the FuncName will be `"TestFunc"` and PluginFunc will be the address of a function in the plugin.

With no luck in searching internet I hope i can find the solution here (Which can be any external library or even ideas)

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz did you even read the last line, how ever edited for better explanation what I want

Comment: I still don't understand your question. What's stopping you from just using DLLs like everyone else does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just incapsulate that functionality in a class, call it for example HookManager:

```
class HookManager {
public:
    void registerHook( const std::string &name, std::function<...> hook );
    void callHooks( const std::string &name );
...
};
```

Of course you would need to put actual signature into `std::function<...>` and modify `callHooks()` accordingly.
So now inside your test function call that hook manager:

```
DWORD TestFunc(int Number)
{
   printf("The number is %i", Number);

   // Plugin codes here
   hookManager.callHooks( "TestFunc" );

   return 0; // Return when we have done our job
}
```

You probably can use `__func__` there instead of hardcoding function name. For hook manager object you can probably use singleton pattern or pass that object as parameter to plugins initialization code and functions that need to call hooks.
Inside you DLL if you use singleton:

```
void TestFuncHook();


BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL,DWORD fdwReason,LPVOID lpvReserved) 
{
   HookManager &hookManager = HookManager::instance();
   hookManager.registerHook( "TestFunc", std::bind( TestFuncHook ) );
   ...
}
```

If hook function does match signature of hook you may omit std::bind. Another solution would be to require plugin to have initialization function with some predefined name, that accepts hookManager as a parameter:

```
extern "C"
void initializeMyPlugin( HookManager &hookManager )
{
   hookManager.registerHook( "TestFunc", std::bind( TestFuncHook ) );
}
```

Now in you main app when you load DLL you lookup for initialization function:

```
HMODULE module = LoadLibrary( "somelibrary.dll" );
FARPROC proc = GetProcAddress( module, "_initializeMyPlugin" );
if( !proc ) {
   // it is not a plugin!
   return;
}
typedef void (*InitilizeFuncPtr)( HookManager & );
reinterpret_cast<InitilizeFuncPtr>( proc )( hookManager);
```

Comment: Thanks for good answer, now would you please show an example of how to code plugin side ?

Comment: @Shahriyar added that code

Comment: I completely have no idea about `registerHook` and `callHooks` functionality -__-